# Making elements unaccessible by date (for an advent calendar)

Tags: javascript, date, if-statement, calendar, addeventlistener

I've recently been working on an advent calendar with vanilla JS and without jquery or using grid (like all of the examples I've seen online).
I can't seem to get the doors to open based on the date. I think the js code is more or less right, but I'm missing the variable that actually gives each of the html elements (doors) a date to check against in the JS file.
So my question is, what am I missing? Does adding a "day" class in the html work?
I haven't found a sample at all with just vanilla JS, so I'm pretty lost.

I've made a very simple codepen with four door elements that have varying dates. The actual project has 25 doors and they are all placed randomly on the backdrop. They also aren't using an alert, but for the sake of showing something, i've changed it to alerts!

I apologize if it's sloppy or hard to read; I'm still quite new to this.

If you need any clarification please let me know in the comments!

Thank you!

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/LovelyAndy/pen/MWebWKy

```js
let d = new Date()
let todaysDate = d.getDate()
const chirstmas = new Date('2020-12-25')
const day = document.querySelectorAll('.day')
const doors = document.querySelectorAll('.door')
const doorBackArray = document.querySelectorAll('.door-back')

doors.forEach((door) => {
  if (todaysDate >= day) {
    door.addEventListener('click', () => {
      door.classList.add('doorOpen')
    })
  } else if (todaysDate < day) {
    door.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert("Not so fast! Come back on the day for the surprise!");
    })
  } else {
    door.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert("It's Christmas baby!");
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.door-position {
  position: absolute;
}

.door-back {
  position: relative;
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  background-image: url('https://preview.redd.it/npq2ab6aepd51.jpg?auto=webp&s=2d44bf582509451d41f9e8add54775e9fb4478fb');
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-size: cover;
}

.door {
  position: absolute;
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  font-family: 'Mountains of Christmas', cursive;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid teal;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: indianred;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-origin: left;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.doorOpen {
  transform: perspective(1200px) translateZ(0px) translateX(0px) translateY(0px) rotateY(-150deg);
}

.d1 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 60px;
}

.d10 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 400px;
}

.d20 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 600px;
}

.d25 {
  top: 100px;
  left: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar-main">
  <div class="door-position d1">
    <div class="door-back">
      <button class="door day">1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="door-position d10">
    <div class="door-back">
      <button class="door day">10</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="door-position d20">
    <div class="door-back">
      <button class="door day">20</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="door-position d25">
    <div class="door-back">
      <button class="door day">25</button>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to move a }) to after `alert("It's Christmas baby!");
    })`

Comment: and remove a dot from `const day = document.querySelectorAll.('.day')`

Comment: You also likely want to spell `chirstmas` `christmas `

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for the corrections! Unfortunately they are now all showing the alert on click. 
I changed the final else to an "else if" and made it (todaysDate === christmas) and now nothing is working

Answer (score 0):

You can use html [data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) to give each element it's opening date.
You would then get that date using the standard element selector and then referencing it's data property.

```
<div class="door-position d1" data-opening-date="12/25/2020">
    <div class="door-back">
      <button class="door day">1</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And you can then get the date on click from the data attribute as so:

```
const door = document.querySelector('.door-back');
if (door.openingDate == myDate) { do something }
```

You can see a complete implementation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Comment: Interesting! 
Firstly, thank you for the response!
So I go through each of the 25 days on the html, add the data attribute and then in the js code, I could right something like:

`code 
 let todaysDate = d.getDate() 
  let myDates = document.querySelectorAll('data-opening-date')

doors.forEach((door) =>{
   if (todaysDate === myDates) {
     alert("SOMETHING!")
}
})`

I feel like the variable I put for the data-opening-dates isn't correct though. 

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: You would go through all the doors and then check for the data-opening-date rather than querying all elements with this data-attribute.
const doors = document.querySelectorAll('.door')
doors.forEach((door) => { door.dataOpeningDate == todaysDate })
Note: To access data attributes you must camel case it.

Comment: Thanks again for the response. I was having a bit of trouble even when doing `door.dataset.openingDate === todaysDate` Like it was listed on MDN. 
Perhaps there some weird cases that make it not work with if statements, but I'll keep messing around with it!

Comment: @LovelyAndy You will need to convert date to a string before comparing, console log both values to see if they match.